# Scheduled task ran without Schedule

Tags: powershell-extensions, scheduled-tasks, scheduler-job

Scheduled task ran without Schedule when PowerShell module is being used. Any fix is available to avoid such triggers?
Steps to Reproduce

1. Create a dummy PowerShell script just to print a line under `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library`.
2. Create an "**Schedule**" under `/sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules`
3. Add `Commands/PowerShell Script Command` as value in command field.
4. Add path to the script created above in items field.

After some time script will get execute automatically without having any value in the Schedule field.

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce any scripts running when the schedule time/date/frequency field is empty on Sitecore 10.3. Please share more details about how you determined that it ran.

Comment: Hi @MichaelWest Thanks for reverting back. We are facing this issue on sitecore 9.3.0. I will attach logs and other details